# Changing values in a column based on condition from table function

Tags: r

I'm working in R. I would like all the values of a column to be 'other' where the number of observations with a factor level in that column are less than some value k.

For example, if I had a dataframe:

```
data.frame('a' = c(rep(1,2),rep(3,20)), 'b' = c(rep('n',4), rep('b',5), rep('g', 13)) )
```

I would want to change all the values of column `b` to 'other' if the number of observations of a particular factor were less than 5. In this case, then I would change all entries where the value was `n` to `'other'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
good <- names(table(dat$b))[table(dat$b)>=5]
levels(dat$b) <- c(levels(dat$b), "other")
dat$b[ !dat$b %in% good ] <- "other"
```

Explanation: Find out the items that should remain, then extend the levels vector so that it can accept an "other" value, then convert all items that are not in the "good" list.